# How to Assign Stop Watch Units of Time to Variables

Tags: python, tkinter

This freely available code is a stop watch GUI application. Upon pressing the stop button, how would one assign the minutes, seconds, and milliseconds to individual variables as m, s, ms?

For starters, I've tried `m = self.timestr.get()[0:2]` in the Stop function but the value is always 00 regardless of the number of minutes.

```
from Tkinter import *
import time

class StopWatch(Frame): 
    """ Implements a stop watch frame widget. """                                                               
    def __init__(self, parent=None, **kw):       
        Frame.__init__(self, parent, kw)
        self._start = 0.0       
        self._elapsedtime = 0.0
        self._running = 0
        self.timestr = StringVar()              
        self.makeWidgets()     

    def makeWidgets(self):                        
        """ Make the time label. """
        l = Label(self, textvariable=self.timestr)
        self._setTime(self._elapsedtime)
        l.pack(fill=X, expand=NO, pady=2, padx=2)                     

    def _update(self):
        """ Update the label with elapsed time. """
        self._elapsedtime = time.time() - self._start
        self._setTime(self._elapsedtime)
        self._timer = self.after(50, self._update)

    def _setTime(self, elap):
        """ Set the time string to Minutes:Seconds:Hundreths """
        minutes = int(elap/60)
        seconds = int(elap - minutes*60.0)
        hseconds = int((elap - minutes*60.0 - seconds)*100)               
        self.timestr.set('%02d:%02d:%02d' % (minutes, seconds, hseconds))

    def Start(self):                                                    
        """ Start the stopwatch, ignore if running. """
        if not self._running:           
            self._start = time.time() - self._elapsedtime
            self._update()
            self._running = 1       

    def Stop(self):                                   
        """ Stop the stopwatch, ignore if stopped. """
        if self._running:
            self.after_cancel(self._timer)           
            self._elapsedtime = time.time() - self._start   
            self._setTime(self._elapsedtime)
            self._running = 0

    def Reset(self):                                 
        """ Reset the stopwatch. """
        self._start = time.time()        
        self._elapsedtime = 0.0   
        self._setTime(self._elapsedtime)


def main():
    root = Tk()
    sw = StopWatch(root)
    sw.pack(side=TOP)

    Button(root, text='Start', command=sw.Start).pack(side=LEFT)
    Button(root, text='Stop', command=sw.Stop).pack(side=LEFT)
    Button(root, text='Reset', command=sw.Reset).pack(side=LEFT)
    Button(root, text='Quit', command=root.quit).pack(side=LEFT)

    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: You could simply save the minutes, seconds and hours that you're computing while the timer is running so you don't have to do a conversion later.

Comment: After debugging my program, the reason why the minutes, seconds, and miliseconds had values of 0 is because in my main program which calls `StopWatch` is because I kept overwriting the stop watch widget. Idiot!

Comment: I don't understand the question. It already counts hours, minutes and seconds.

Comment: It's just a basic math equation.

Comment: `hours = int(elap/3600)
 minutes = int(elap/60 - hours*60)
 seconds = int(elap - hours * 3600 - minutes * 60.0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `_setTimer` you create

```
 minutes = int(elap/60)
 seconds = int(elap - minutes*60.0)
 hseconds = int((elap - minutes*60.0 - seconds)*100)
```

so use `self.minutes`, `self.seconds`, `self.hseconds` and you will not have to use `self.timestr.get()`